# How to label Churn/Not Churn and perform Survival Analysis on Transactional Data without Subscription

Tags: machine-learning, survival, panel-data, cox-model, churn

I have longitudinal transaction data of a retail store where each row is a transaction done by an individual. I would like to perform a survival analysis to analyse how long a customer will transact before churning. For CoxPH model, it requires **tenure and churn variable** among other variables. I am not sure what is the correct approach to prepare these variables for this analysis.
How to label whether **a person has churned** other than having a threshold of 45days or 2 months to decide it. Also, what is the correct way to represent tenure.

Below is the sample of data

````
Id.    Visit_date.       Amount.   Tenure     Churn     Age     Income
1.     04/03/2020        500        ?           ?       40      56K
1.     05/03/2020        300        ?           ?       32      60K
1.     05/23/2020        800        ?           ?       28      90K
1.     07/04/2020        700        ?           ?       40      56K
2.     02/03/2020        500        ?           ?       43      50K
2.     05/12/2020        300        ?           ?       60      90K
3.     03/23/2020        800        ?           ?       18      80K
4.     07/04/2020        700        ?           ?       20      40K

```
````

Answer (score 2):

It is *your* decision on what you define as churn. This is something to discuss with business people who are going to use those results. The definitions will vary on case-by-case basis. Usually what is used is some threshold that is meaningful from business perspective.

Comment: thanks for the response. Also, suppose a threshold is used to define the Churn, then how should i setup **tenure** variable in case of this longitudinal data considering the above sample data where user_id 1 has made four transactions.